# Expand VD in Raid PERC H710, Dell R720 mini

Tags: raid10, vds, dell-poweredge

I have purchased Dell R720 server with PERC H710 Raid Controller. Initially I have configured RAID-10 with 6 SAS 300GB Drives. Installed Win2008 R2. 
Raid10:
After deployment I come to add 2 more 300GB to array. Now I am unable to expand these two drives into existing RAID-10 neither Online nor from RAID Configuration Utility (PERC H710 Mini Bios Configuration Utility 4.03-0002)
In RAID-BIOS "Expand VB Size" option is disabled.

? how can I expand my RAID-10, and add more drives to array?

Answer (score 3):

See Perc H710 [User Guide](ftp://ftp.dell.com/Manuals/Common/poweredge-rc-h310_User%27s%20Guide_en-us.pdf), p 18 :

> Reconfiguration Of Virtual Disks
>
> An online virtual disk can be reconfigured in ways that expands its capacity and/or change its RAID level.
>
> NOTE: **Spanned virtual disks such as RAID 10, 50, and 60 cannot be reconfigured**.

As I understand it, Raid 10 VD cannot be expanded.

Answer (score 1):

In dell server if you want to change the VD you need to go into the OS and into "Dell Server Administrator" on the VD screen you will have an option to reconfigure the VD.

Note #1 - I will admit i have never tried doing this on a RAID 10, 50, 60. only on 1, 5, 6.
Note #2 - Make sure you have a backup!!!! one of the times during the reconfigure the OS crashed and the RAID array went on a fritz!